# FullCalendar - How to find all events that match a particular date?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Q: How do I programmatically find all events that occurs at a given date?

In a `TimeGrid` view, Let's say I'm catching a `click time` event when clicking on a cell. I would like to know what event(s) might have overlaps with that time. Of course it's not just the one in the cell I just clicked on, it's also recurring events and all-day events.

I just can't find any utils to do that kind of search/filter and I'm not sure I want to re-implement a whole procedure from scratch.

Note: I'm looking at the `ListView` that have a `eventStoreToSegs` call that might do a similar job. But any help will be welcome.

Comment: You want to do this in fullcalendar 4 or 5? You've tagged both. It's not impossible the solution might be different depending on the version.

Comment: Using 4.4 right now but will switch to 5 pretty soon. So I guess a solution for 5 will give me that incentive :-)

Comment: Also, if it matters, I'm on React

Comment: I would expect that [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) should do most or all of what you want. It'll stop anyone from selecting any time periods which overlap with existing events at the same time, including (as it mentions) all-day events. It doesn't mention recurring events specifically and I haven't got time to test it, but I'd be surprised if it didn't catch those too.

Comment: Well spotted  @ADyson! It takes a little bit of management to collect the end-of-selection overlaps (rather than a single on-the-fly event) but it does the job.